# A regex for validate image name using in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

In my application I save images name ( and only name not url) in my database. I extract the name from their url. The database field has max length 40. So the image pattern must be some thing like this:

> LEETERS NOT IMPORTANT + **"/" + 36 letter + "." + "jpg/png/bmp/gif"** *= 40*

I create a pattern and used that to textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstSrc" runat="server" CssClass="firstImage imgUrl largeBox numberOrEnglish"
                        pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._/%:+-]+\/[A-Za-z0-9._/%+-]{0,36}\.+(jpg|png|gif|bmp|JPG|PNG|GIF|BMP)"></asp:TextBox>
```

And it works fine. Now i want use this in javascript but for this stirng:

**2013-10-10T094007Z_1042484401_GM1E9AA1CN101_RTRMADP_3_THAILA‌​ND.jpg**

```
var isNameValid = "[A-Za-z0-9._/%:+-]+\/[A-Za-z0-9._/%+-]{0,36}\.+(jpg|png|gif|bmp|JPG|PNG|GIF|BMP)".test(file.name);
```

Does not work, And this one:

```
var isNameValid = /^[A-Za-z0-9._/%:+-]+\/[A-Za-z0-9._/%+-]{0,36}\.+(jpg|png|gif|bmp|JPG|PNG|GIF|BMP)$/.test(file.name);
```

is always false. What is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Tried escaping `/` in the last pattern? What is the test string?

Comment: Test string is the name of image extracted from its url.

Comment: what's in file.name? you need to show what's actually in file.name.

Comment: 2013-10-10T094007Z_1042484401_GM1E9AA1CN101_RTRMADP_3_THAILAND.jpg

Comment: Could you please give me your regex?

Comment: What is the problem of my question to gave me -1? This made me 'Question ban' but why?

Comment: the name doesn't have a slash in it, but your regex requires one.

Comment: Thank you very much @Shiping. If you write this as answer i will check that as the true answer.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi okay i posted the answer so you can close it.  you asked about why someone voted your question down, i think it's because you didn't give enough info for people to see what's the problem.  as you know now, without seeing what's in the file name, it's hard to see what may be the problem. when you debug issues like this, you first should check what's actually in the string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133995/discussion-between-farzin-kanzi-and-shiping).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the name doesn't have a slash in it, but your regex requires one.